# How to change the link after marking question as duplicate

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

So after marking a question as a duplicate and provided the link to the existing question, the link provided was wrong by a copy/paste mistake.
If I want to change the link I can't find a way to do so,
[image]

And retracting the flag and re-opening a new one wont work either
[image]

And wont this lead to decreasing my stats in **helpful flags** section ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I'd just add the correct link as a comment.

Comment: Yes that's what I've done but I guess that it would be better if there was a way.

Comment: Dupehammers can edit the link now, as Paul alludes to. You could try to grab one in a chat room or something and ask them nicely :)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately you cannot change the link.  The best you can do is if you catch it in the edit window is to retract the close flag and then edit the auto comment that was posted under you name to the right link.  If you missed the edit window then still retract the flag and then you can delete the comment and add a new one with the right link.